# Entity properties are not changing after calling dao.findByID(id)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entitymanager

The question here is why the entity properties are not being saved after calling some setters of the entity. Usually when changing a property of a managed entity, it should propagate to the database.

Take a look at this example:

```
@Service
public class SystemServiceImpl implements SystemService {

@Autowired
private SystemDao systemDao;


@Override
@Transactional
public System replace(Long systemID) {

    // External system to replace
    System system = systemDao.findByID(systemID);
    if (null != system) {
        system.setName("Test"); // Calling findByID again shows that this call did not have any effect.
    }
    return system;
}

}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "db.system")
public class System {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long systemID;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "system", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

public Long getSystemID() {
    return systemID;
}

public void setSystemID(Long systemID) {
    this.systemID = systemID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
    return customers;
}

public void setCustomers(List<Customer> customers) {
    this.customers = customers;
}
}
```

If I call systemDao.merge after the system.setName("Test") then it is saved to the database. I feel I should not have to call merge as this should be a managed entity.

I tried having the replace method both with @Transactional and without, and both are producing the same result.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: can you add the @entity class, especially the definition of columns which do not casue the update to trigger

Comment: also isnt that replace method part of some higher level transactional method?

Comment: updated the answer, also the replace method is a custom method only existing in the interface i created.

Comment: Are you calling `.save()`? I don't think without calling `.save()` or any other related method, DB will get updated.

Comment: Would you provide us the DAO class?

Comment: Afaik, you dont need to call the save if it is managed.

Comment: I don't know about any thing like this. Would like to read about it. You got some links?

Comment: The Dao is a customised class. The important thing here is why the Entity is not updated.

Comment: Here: If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation, however, the merge operation is cascaded to entities referenced by relationships from X if these relationships have been annotated with the cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL annotation.

Comment: Just before your null check after you fetch the `system`, fire a `systemDao.save(system)` (not after making the changes to `system`) and let me know if it persisted the changes.

Comment: @VikasPrasad systemDao.merge(system); does not make any difference if called before the if-statement.

Comment: Or for the second time instead of using `findByID(systemID)`, try with just `findByName('test')`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155446/discussion-between-vikas-prasad-and-firre).

Comment: quoting the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788484/why-do-changes-to-my-jpa-entity-not-get-persisted-to-the-database : *An important point to realize here is that "adding an entity to the persistence context" does not have to be equal to "stored in the database". The persistence provider is free to postpone the database interaction as long as it thinks is reasonable.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was happening when I was running my integration tests. Turns out that Transactional is not doing anything because there is no session. The solution to this was to add a Transactional to my tests.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour can be explained if SystemDao.findByID() returns a detached object. Make sure that SystemDao does not use RequiresNew-Transaction or explicitly detach the object after loading it.
It would really help if you posted the code of SystemDao and any relevant configuration entries (Spring, entity manager config, ...).

Comment: Why would the entity detach after findByID? If that is possible then please provide the way that could happen. Maybe an example config that I can search in my source code.

Comment: The entity can detach if you explicitly detach it em.detach(object) or call em.clear(). It can also become detached if the code is run in a separate transction, as mentioned above.

Comment: I can tell you that my dao extends HibernateDaoSupport. I am also running Spring 3.2.

Comment: Without posting your SystemDao code and the config, we can't help you. From what you've stated above, everything points to the fact that the object is loaded in a different transaction and not part of the current session when being modified. Btw. HibernateDaoSupport is deprected.

Comment: public interface SystemDao extends HibernateDaoSupport<System, Long> {
    System findByName(String name);
}